# I want to check whether or not a certain port is open (Haskell)?

Tags: http, haskell, port, ghc

I want to check whether or not a certain port is open on a certain host. How can I do that? After I've called `connectTo` and what's next, how can I actually know if a port is open?

```
main = do
  withSocketsDo $ do
    h <- connectTo "some_host.com" $ PortNumber 1234
    --- and....?
```

Comment: If the host is protected by portknocking, even nmap will think all its ports are closed. How exactly do you want to query the ports ?

Comment: @V.Semeria, we can assume it's not protected.

Answer (score 2):

The main task here is to connect to call `connect` and **capture exactly the case that the host refused the connection** (as opposed to the host not existing or being unroutable).

A solution using the new `Network.Socket` API, not the deprecated `Socket` module, using the [`unliftio`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio) package's for async exception handling safety (you can use `Control.Exception` instead, but it will be [less safe](https://haskell.fpcomplete.com/tutorial/exceptions)):

```hs
import           Data.Word (Word8)
import           Foreign.C.Error (Errno(..), eCONNREFUSED)
import           GHC.IO.Exception (IOException(..))
import           Network.Socket (PortNumber, socket, connect, close', Family(AF_INET), SocketType(Stream), SockAddr(SockAddrInet), tupleToHostAddress)
import           UnliftIO.Exception (try, bracket, throwIO)


-- | Checks whether @connect()@ to a given TCPv4 `SockAddr` succeeds or
-- returns `eCONNREFUSED`.
--
-- Rethrows connection exceptions in all other cases (e.g. when the host
-- is unroutable).
isPortOpen :: SockAddr -> IO Bool
isPortOpen sockAddr = do
  bracket (socket AF_INET Stream 6 {- TCP -}) close' $ \sock -> do
    res <- try $ connect sock sockAddr
    case res of
      Right () -> return True
      Left e ->
        if (Errno <$> ioe_errno e) == Just eCONNREFUSED
          then return False
          else throwIO e


-- | Creates a `SockAttr` from host IP and port number.
--
-- Example:
-- > simpleSockAddr (127,0,0,1) 8000
simpleSockAddr :: (Word8, Word8, Word8, Word8) -> PortNumber -> SockAddr
simpleSockAddr addr port = SockAddrInet port (tupleToHostAddress addr)
```

Then you can do:

```
> isPortOpen (simpleSockAddr (127,0,0,1) 8000)
True
```

Full module in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nh2/0a1442eb71ec0405a1e3ce83a467dfde).

Answer (score 1):

If `connectTo` returns, then the port is open. Otherwise it will throw exceptions like

```
*** Exception: connect: failed (Connection timed out (WSAETIMEDOUT))
```

or

```
*** Exception: connect: failed (Connection refused (WSAECONNREFUSED))
```

So you could do

```
import Network(connectTo, PortID(..), PortNumber(..))
import Control.Exception(try, SomeException)
import System.IO(Handle)

isPortOpen :: String -> PortNumber -> IO Bool
isPortOpen host port = do
  h <- try $ connectTo host (PortNumber port) :: IO (Either SomeException Handle)
  return $ case h of
    Left _ -> False
    Right _ -> True
```

Comment: it always returns False, in particular for localhost. have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried it on localhost, with a small web server I have on my machine. You can check what exception it throws in your case.

Comment: or maybe not always, but it seems in some cases it returns false instead of true.

Comment: If you'd like it to always return true then just `isPortOpen _ _ = true` ;-).  Seriously though you need to be more specific, in my tests this routine returns true for open TCP ports and false for closed ports.

Comment: This solution leaks the created Handle `h`. GC will clean it up eventually, but if you call `isPortOpen` many times in a loop, you may run out of handles before GC kicks in. You should probably `hClose` the handle in the `Right` branch. Also, the `SomeException` catch-all is quite generic, you should better catch specifically `IOError`. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/nh2/3fb70820d89f5e9f6d1ee80415c53a72) of a more complete solution.

Comment: My [previous gist](https://gist.github.com/nh2/3fb70820d89f5e9f6d1ee80415c53a72) is now outdated (I updated it to say why). I've posted a [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139787/i-want-to-check-whether-or-not-a-certain-port-is-open-haskell/57022572#57022572) with [better gist](https://gist.github.com/nh2/0a1442eb71ec0405a1e3ce83a467dfde).